# Tratamento de Imagens Python

Tags: python, postgresql, django

Estou com uma dúvida aqui de arquitetura:

A aplicação que estamos construindo, possui uma carga de imagens pro sistema. São fotos de anúncios, e cada um pode carregar 12 fotos. Estes anúncios são dinâmicos, ou seja podem estar disponíveis hoje e amanhã não mais. Pesquisando muito, verifiquei duas formas de fazer:

1. gravar as imagens em uma pasta local no server e no banco gravar somente o path da imagem. Isto economizaria um bom espaço, porém dificultaria o controle das coisas, pois teríamos de ter uma regra para excluir as imagens conforme os anúncios forem sendo retirados. Porém uma imagem de 900k teria no servidor 900k realmente. O backup também seria mais complicado.
2. converter as imagens em string base64 e gravar direto no banco, o que facilitaria a manutenção, porém em teste que fiz a imagem que tem 900k ficou com 3,88M na base. Então como seriam muitas imagens, tenho receio do servidor escalar muito rápido e ficarmos com um custo muito elevado.

Não consegui sucesso gravando como ByteA.

Estou usando Python 3, Django 2 e PostgresSQL.

Se alguém tiver uma sugestão mais assertiva seria de grande ajuda.

Comment: Eu recomendaria usar um serviço storage em cloud, como um AWS ou CloudFlare etc

Comment: @carlosgaddini, sim muito bem comentado. Toda aplicação roda em um AWS. Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a linha sugerida no comentário do colega @carlosgadinni, a utilização de um serviço de [Armazenamento em Nuvem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_storage) poderia ser uma solução bastante versátil e **escalável** para o seu problema.

Os provedores de serviços de armazenamento em nuvem quase sempre disponibilizam uma [API Web](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_aplica%C3%A7%C3%B5es) para manipulação dos dados, possibilitando a leitura, gravação e consulta das suas imagens diretamente na nuvem, o que facilitaria bastante a integração do seu sistema com o serviço de amazenamento.

O seu banco de dados armazenaria apenas um identificador ou a URL correspondente a imagem, delegando toda a complexidade do armazenamento das imagens exclusivamente para o serviço.

Comment: @lLacobus alguma sugestão de contratação nesse caso? No seu exemplo eu teria a imagem armazenada fora do meu server e faria a busca um uma url de serviço, correto?

Answer (score 0):

Eu recomendaria salvar em um diretório do que diretamente dentro do banco de dados como um blob. Cada anuncio tem uma pasta nesse diretório com as imagens dentro desta pasta, se o anuncio for removido, basta remover a pasta com as imagens dentro.

Comment: Show de bola Luis Eduardo. Achei mesmo que o caminho seria melhor por ai. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Isso vai ficar caro heim! melhor prestar atenção no comentário do @carlosgaddini feito na pergunta.